# SORT a specific value in mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have data set with full of data...

```
 Id  |  loc    |SubLoc    |beds
 1      15       5803      1
 2      15       5803      1
 3      16       2813      1
 4      16       2813      2
 5      16       2830      1
 6      20       2020      4
 7      19       2513      3
```

I have this php/mysql code to traverse it

```
select id,loc,SubLoc,beds from table  where id != 144  AND price > 140000 AND price < 210000 AND category_id=1

while($rw = mysql_fetch_array($rs2)){}
```

Now i want to sort $rw in this manner

I have three values

```
loc=16,SubLoc=2813,beds=1
```

I want to show same result but show all results in this manner

```
1- having loc==16 on top then
2- having SubLoc = 2813 then
3- having beds  = 1
```

and then rest of results

How this can be done in php?

**UPDATED**

I want to get these Ids

```
3 as it matches 3 parameters
4 as it matches 2 parameters
5 as it matches 2 parametrs
1 as it matches 1 parameter
```

and so on

Comment: why not sort it in mysql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
select id,loc,SubLoc,beds from table1
where loc = 16 or subloc = 2813 or beds =1
order by 
   case when loc = 16      then 0 
        when subloc = 2813 then 1
        when beds = 1      then 2 end asc
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04e1ac/6)

to get other results also without matching then use this:

```
 select id,loc,SubLoc,beds from table1
 order by 
     case when loc  = 16     then 0 
          when subloc = 2813 then 1
          when beds = 1      then 2 
          else 3 end asc
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04e1ac/8)

**EDIT:** to include all cases use this:

```
  select id,loc,SubLoc,beds from table1
  order by 
  case when loc = 16 and subloc=2013 and beds = 1 then 0 
       when loc = 16      and subloc = 2813       then 1
       when loc = 16      and beds = 1            then 2
       when subloc = 2813 and beds = 1            then 3
       when loc = 16                              then 4 
       when subloc = 2813                         then 5
       when beds = 1                              then 6
       else 7 end asc
```

Comment: Here is One Issue,I want to check if both loc & subLoc matches then it should be on top...here is not such case

Comment: Baby,you are real GURU

Comment: hehe im your baby :) ?, you make me feel good :), i wish so hehe

Answer (score 0):

Try with order

`ORDER BY SubLoc=16 DESC,loc, beds`

Comment: This won't work, Subloc has higher values then the desired records that need to be on top.

Comment: this will give me loc=15 first..which i do not want...i need equal to in sort also

Comment: then what you want not by order?